# How to incrementally change a string in a file?

Tags: python

I need to search through a file, and change each occurrence of a string.  But, each time I change the string, it needs to be something slightly different.

For example, I want to find "foo" in a file. The first time I find it, I want to change it to "bar1".  The next time I find it, I want to change it to "bar2", etc etc

What's the best way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you look for a pattern even within a word or must it be a word?

Comment: Whenever you find a match for the string, replace it with the string concatenated with a counter, and increment the counter. You can use `str.replace()` for this.

Comment: Do you have a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with a closure and by giving a callback to `re.sub` function

```py
import re

def incrementalSub(repl):
    increment = 0
    def subClosure(matchobj):
        nonlocal increment
        increment += 1
        return f'{repl}{increment}'
    return subClosure

def incrementalSubFile(filename, pattern, repl):
    with open(filename) as file:
        print(re.sub(pattern, incrementalSub(repl), file.read()))
```

**Example**

`test.txt`

```
foo f zzfeffzeqf foo   dDEFFezfef

fsfds foo FDFEF foo
```

```py
incrementalSubFile('test.txt',r'foo','bar')
```

```
bar1 f zzfeffzeqf bar2   dDEFFezfef

fsfds bar3 FDFEF bar4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following code should do what you want:

```py
def replace_incrementally(file, to_replace, replace_with)
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        new_lines = []
        counter = 0
        for line in f.readlines():
            res = [i for i in range(len(line)) if line.startswith(to_replace, i)] 
            for i in range(len(res)):
                line.replace(to_replace+"".format(counter), replace_with, 1)
                counter += 1
            new_lines.append(line)

    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(new_lines)
```